# ¿Como volver al inicio si la condición no se cumple? JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que me pide dos números, lo que quiero hacer es que si estos dos números son menores o iguales a cero (No cumplen la condición de ser mayores a 0), me vuelva a pedir los 2 números sin necesidad de darle a compilar al programa de nuevo, este es mi código;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int resultado = 0;
    System.out.println("Este programa realiza la suma de dos numeros mediante sumas sucesivas");
    System.out.println("Ingresa el primer numero (N)");
    int N = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo numero (M)");
    int M = leer.nextInt();
    if (N <= 0 & M <= 0){
        System.out.println("Los numeros tienen que ser mayores a cero");
   //Aquí es donde no se que poner para que vuelva al principio si la condición no se
     cumple y me pida los 2 números de nuevo
    }
```

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es un ciclo `do while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tengo un programa que me pide dos números, lo que quiero hacer es que si estos dos números son menores o iguales a cero, me vuelva a pedir los 2 números

En estos casos una buena solución es un ciclo **`do while`**

También te he cambiado la condición `(N <= 0 & M <= 0)` por esta otra `(N <= 0 || M <= 0)`, ya que estaba mal si alguno de los datos introducidos era 0 o menor. Se tiene que cumplir al menos una condición, no las dos para que volvamos a repetir toda esta parte de código.

```
public class DoWhileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int resultado = 0, N, M;
        System.out.println("Este programa realiza la suma de dos numeros mediante sumas sucesivas");

        do {
            System.out.println("Ingresa el primer numero (N)");
            N = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo numero (M)");
            M = leer.nextInt();

        } while (N <= 0 || M <= 0);

        int suma = N+M;
        System.out.println("La suma de N y M es: " + suma);
        System.out.println("Fin programa");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar un ciclo iterativo como por ejemplo un while

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
 int resultado = 0;
 System.out.println("Este programa realiza la suma de dos numeros mediante sumas sucesivas");
  //declarar las variables primero
  int N=0;
  int M=0;
 //ciclo que se repite hasta que los dos numeros sean mayor que 0
 while(N<=0 && M<=0 ){ 
   System.out.println("Ingresa el primer numero (N)");
   N = leer.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo numero (M)");
   M = leer.nextInt();
 }
```

Comment: Y como entra dentro del `while`

Comment: Pero las variables no existen, por lo que da error